# How to find an element in a XML file that contains an eclamation mark in the tag name?

Tags: python, lxml

My xml file has in the beginning something like this:

How to extract this tag from lxml?

I've tried:
tree = etree.parse("file_name")
el = tree.find("!DOCTYPE")

But it does not work...
Thanks for the help

Comment: That's not an element, that's the [Document Type Declaration](https://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#dt-doctype). Can you be more specific about what you're trying to do with the doctype declaration?

Comment: I just want to be able to have as an element object in order to add it as a child node to some other element object

Comment: You can get the doctype with `tree.docinfo.doctype`, but that's just a string. You can't add the doctype as a child node to some other element; that breaks the rules of [well-formed xml](https://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#sec-well-formed).